# how to get modulus difference of values of two json objects in python

Tags: python, arrays, json, key, modulo

I have two JSON arrays , I need to get the modulus difference of the JSON object keys. My array list can have 1000s of elements. How to calculate it efficiently? Is there a way to do it parallelly without using loop?

For example

```
js1 = [{'myVal':100},{'myVal':200}]
js2 = [{'myVal':500},{'myVal':800}]
```

Result should be :

```
[{'myVal':400},{'myVal':600}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is 2 way to acheive it :

- Using `map`

```
js1 = [{'myVal':100},{'myVal':200}]
js2 = [{'myVal':500},{'myVal':800}]  
result = list(map(lambda x, y: {'myVal': y['myVal'] - x['myVal']}, js1, js2))
print(result)
```

- Using list comprehension

```
js1 = [{'myVal':100},{'myVal':200}]
js2 = [{'myVal':500},{'myVal':800}]
result = [{'myVal': y['myVal'] - x['myVal']} for x,y in zip(js1,js2)]
print(result)
```

They will both output

```
[{'myVal': 400}, {'myVal': 600}]
```

Comment: executable -- Does number of objects and keys affect the performance in this? Which one is better out of two? How do i exactly check it?

Comment: `map` or list comprehension is more efficient than using a loop, as it allows the calculations to be performed in parallel. The one you're more comfortable with

Comment: What do you mean, "allows the calculations to be performed in parallel"? There won't be any implicit multi-threaded execution here, no. Each `-` operation will still be performed one after the other.

Comment: I mean, the calculation is operating on both array